# C typedef struct with pragma translated to Python in python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have this C-Headerfile:

```
#pragma pack (push,1)
typedef struct {
  uint16_t DLLFailureCode;
  uint8_t ConnectionStatus;
  uint32_t SystemFailureCode;
} TConnectionResult;
```

How would you implement the equivalent to this in Python (if that is even possible)?

I tried the following way, but it doesn't seem right: Why?

```
from ctypes import *
    class Program:
        def __init__(self):
            self.DLL = CDLL(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Program\epMCOMLib.dll"))
    
            self.Handle = c_uint32(0)
            self.Handle_p = pointer(self.Handle)
    
        def QueryOpenConnectionStatus(self):
            p = POINT(0, 0, 0)
            p_p = pointer(p)
            print("OpenQuery", self.DLL.QueryOpenConnectionStatus(self.Handle, p_p))
            print(p.DLLFailureCode, p.ConnectionStatus, p.SystemFailureCode)
    
        class POINT(Structure):
            _pack_ = 1
            _fields_ = [
                ('DLLFailureCode', c_uint16),
                ('ConnectionStatus', c_uint8),
                ('SystemFailureCode', c_uint32)]
```

My goal is to be able to run the following method successfully in Python:

```
   DLLIMPORT void __cdecl QueryOpenConnectionStatus(uint32_t Handle,
                                                 TConnectionResult * Result);
```

Comment: As far as I know, what you did should have worked.  Could you give more specifics on what happened instead of its working?

Comment: I noticed that the original structure starts with unsigned (uint16_t), but you defined it as signed (c_int16).

Comment: uint16_t is correct sorry for my correction!

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem right" mean?  Are you getting meaningful failure codes  from the `TConnectionResult`?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Also, you've just set `Handle` to zero.  Seem like there should be some kind of `OpenConnection` call to initialize the handle.  Ideally, make a simple code in C that works, *then* port to Python.  Show us the simple C code for reference.

Comment: Yes that's right. I posted a new question for the `OpenConnection` here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191182/translate-c-header-file-in-python).

Why I know something is wrong is because `DLLFailureCode`, `ConnectionStatus`, `SystemFailureCode` all give me a zero. But actually `ConnectionStatus` should give me a 1. I integrated the DLL into LABVIEW and in my opinion made everything the same and there it works without any problems. That means either I'm doing something wrong in `OpenConnection` or `QueryOpenConnectionStatus`.
I would be so grateful if you could help me!