# Translate C header file in Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have this C-Headerfile:

```
#pragma pack (push,1)
    typedef struct {
      uint16_t DLLFailureCode;
      uint8_t ConnectionStatus;
      uint32_t SystemFailureCode;
    } TConnectionResult;
    
    typedef void (__cdecl *TOnConnectionEvent)(uint32_t          Handle,
                                               TConnectionResult ConnectionStatus);
    
    DLLIMPORT uint16_t __cdecl OpenConnection(uint8_t            PortType, 
                                              char *             PortName, 
                                              TOnConnectionEvent OnConnectSuccess, 
                                              uint32_t *         Handle);
```

And I implemented it as below, but for some reason I can't get any connection. Did I make a mistake or is it the DLL?

```
class Program:
def __init__(self):
    self.DLL = CDLL(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Program\epMCOMLib.dll"))
    self.Handle = c_uint32(0)
    self.Handle_p = pointer(self.Handle)

def OPEN(self):
    PortType = c_uint8(0)
    PortName = c_char_p(b'COM1')
    OnConnectSuccess = c_uint32(0)
    self.DLL.OpenConnection(PortType, PortName, OnConnectSuccess, self.Handle_p)
```

Comment: What do you mean by no connection? What error is it giving you?

Comment: It will not give an error, but with another call from the DLL nothing happens. So I think I'm passing something wrong with OpenConnection?

Comment: What is `TOnConnectionEvent` declared as in C?  What does the return value represent?

Comment: I have completed the header file. `TOnConnectionEvent` should represent a callback.

Comment: Should `TConnectionResult ConnectionStatus` be `TConnectionResult* ConnectionStatus`.  Structures are usually passed by address.  There are slight changes to my answer if so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example given your C declarations.  I recommend using `.argtypes` and `.restype` to declare your function parameters and return value so `ctypes` can do argument checking.  Passing a `c_uint32(0)` for `Handle` is incorrect on a 64-bit system but *might* work on a 32-bit system.  Use `None` for a NULL pointer or you can make a callback as demonstrated below using `CFUNCTYPE` as the callback type.

test.c (MSVC compile: cl /LD /W4 test.c)

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct {
  uint16_t DLLFailureCode;
  uint8_t ConnectionStatus;
  uint32_t SystemFailureCode;
} TConnectionResult;
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef void (__cdecl *TOnConnectionEvent)(uint32_t          Handle,
                                           TConnectionResult ConnectionStatus);

__declspec(dllexport)
uint16_t __cdecl OpenConnection(uint8_t            PortType,
                                char *             PortName,
                                TOnConnectionEvent OnConnectSuccess,
                                uint32_t *         Handle)
{
    TConnectionResult result = {1, 2, 3};
    *Handle = 123;
    OnConnectSuccess(*Handle, result);
    return 1;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

class TConnectionResult(ct.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (('DLLFailureCode', ct.c_uint16),
                ('ConnectionStatus', ct.c_uint8),
                ('SystemFailureCode', ct.c_uint32))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'TConnectionResult(DLLFailureCode={self.DLLFailureCode}, ' \
               f'ConnectionStatus={self.ConnectionStatus}, ' \
               f'SystemFailureCode={self.SystemFailureCode})'

TOnConnectionEvent = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.c_uint32, TConnectionResult)

@TOnConnectionEvent
def callback(handle, status):
    print(f'{handle=}, {status=}')

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.OpenConnection.argtypes = ct.c_uint8, ct.c_char_p, TOnConnectionEvent, ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint32)
dll.OpenConnection.restype = ct.c_uint16

port_type = 0
port_name = b'COM1'
handle = ct.c_uint32()
result = dll.OpenConnection(port_type, port_name, callback, ct.byref(handle))
print(f'{result=} handle={handle.value}')
```

Output:

```py
handle=123, status=TConnectionResult(DLLFailureCode=1, ConnectionStatus=2, SystemFailureCode=3)
result=1 handle=123
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you use `byref` for the handle?

Comment: @Robin `byref` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference)) is a more efficient version of `pointer` and passes the object by reference, equivalent to C `int x; func(&x);`.  `pointer` does more work and the way it is used in your example is more like C `int x; int* y = &x; func(y);`.